# Generate a link to download the mobile application from the website

Tags: html, web, mobile, google-play, app-store

I want to know how can we display a link to download the app from the specific store when the user is on mobile version of the website, like the picture in the example:

[image: Netflix app]

I want to know if there is a way to generate this banner or something like that
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS you want to look into "Smart App Banners": `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=123456789">`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html (That is the Netflix example you screenshotted)

For Android you want to use: `<meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.packagename.app">`

Comment: In case custom behaviour is needed and perhaps more control as well, [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js) can be used. Low footprint, no external dependencies, e.g. jQuery.